# jquery mobile grid space between input boxes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How do I set the space between the input boxes in this grid? At the moment they are being formatted one next to the other. Would like a slight space:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <input type="text" id="pobox" name="pobox" autocomplete="false" placeholder="P.O. Box:" class="inputshort" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" autocomplete="false" placeholder="City.." required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty common problem. Have you tried padding on the `.ui-block-*` elements?

Comment: Try padding or margin (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: `.ui-field-contain` padding sorted the issue. Was trying padding on the wrong element.